# Find and replace certain text unti; next occurence of a character

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a xml and json content displayed as string in UI and within it, content looks like `id="id"` for xml and   `"id" : "id"`, for json.
I want to replace both with empty string, below soluting solves it

```
schemeXml = schemeXml.replace(/"id" : "id",/g, '');
schemeXml = schemeXml.replace(/id="id"/g, '');
```

But problem is it may also contain `id="123"` and `"id" : "123"`,
or any value for id.

I need a regex to solve this. Please help me

Comment: You should parse the JSON/XML instead

Comment: Cant do that, because content with id is required in the same page based on request

Answer (score 0):

You should really be parsing this first - but if you don't want to, just match a double quote, any value except another double quote zero or more times, then a closing double quote:

```
schemeXml.replace(/"id" : "[^"]*",/g, "");
```

Comment: This isn't replacing anything